# URL Rewrite with Google Tag Manager script issues

Tags: html, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

In Google Tag Manager, there is a 3rd party script that is added to each one of my pages on my site.

The script looks like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    (function(a,b,c,d){
    a='https://www.test1.com/proxydirectory/tags/12512/tag.js';
    b=document;c='script';d=b.createElement(c);d.src=a;
    d.type='text/java'+c;d.async=true;
    d.id='cjapitag';
    a=b.getElementsByTagName(c)[0];a.parentNode.insertBefore(d,a)
    })();
   </script>
```

According to the 3rd party instructions:
I will need to set up a reverse proxy from my own domain to their servers. The reverse proxy will send requests that start with the following path:

```
https://www.test1.com/proxydirectory/
```

And proxy those request back to their servers:

```
https://www.theirserver.com/
```

Before adding the rewrite, when I open my pages I get the following in my console after creating the Google Tag Manager stuff:

> VM38:1 GET https://www.test1.com/proxydirectory/tags/12512/tag.js
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

I figure that is because I am not rewriting the URL yet.  Cool, at least I know the tag manager is setting my pages. So now for the rewrite.

I attempted a rewrite in IIS URL Rewrite, so that it will rewrite the `https://www.test1.com/proxydirectory/tags/12512/tag.js` to `https://www.theirserver.com/tags/12512/tag.js` with the following rule attempts :

Attempt #1:

```
<rule name="ReverseProxy">
        <match url="https://www.test1.com/proxydirectory/" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="https://www.theirserver.com/" />
    </rule>
```

Attempt #2:

```
   <rule name="ReverseProxy">
        <match url="proxydirectory/(.*)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="https://www.theirserver.com/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
```

Both of these attempts after rebuilding and reloading the page, even restarting the IIS server, did not work.  I still get

> VM38:1 GET https://www.test1.com/proxydirectory/tags/12512/tag.js
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

and yes the 3rd Party server tag.js file does exist and the URL is correct (didn't post the real one here)

Not sure what to do.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Attempt #2 rule you tried seems to be fine, I suggest you use failed request tracing to get detailed error information.

Comment: @samwu I'm not sure how to do that.  Is that in the IIS Manager somewhere

Comment: You can refer to this link: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules).